# Junk characters on console when execute assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Beginner to assembly programming for x86. I have a simple asm file which I assemble using nasm version - NASM version 2.10rc6 compiled on Jun  6 2011, for windows(My windows is Windowa-7 64 bit). NASM is downloaded from [here](http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.10rc6/win32/) ( nasm-2.10rc6-win32.zip).

```
ORG 100
USE16

    mov ah, 09
    mov dx, msg
    int 21h

    mov ah, 01
    int 21h
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h

    msg db 'Hello assembly', 0Ah, '$'
```

Then I assemble using command -

> nasm -f bin hello.asm -o hello.com

Then I run the generated executable hello.com using Dosbox(Dos emulator for 64 bit OS Windows-7).
When it runs the output output on the console has my string 'Hello assembly' plus some junk characters/control characters printed before it, as shown below:

[image]

What is the reason for this. Anything wrong in the code?

What do I need to do to fix this?

EDIT: When i tried to give a option -f to nasm to generate a specific type of executable output , e.g. Win32 or Win64 output i keep getting error saying:

```
nasm -f win64 hello.asm -o hello.com

hello.asm:1: error: parser: instruction expected
```

What is it expecting? How can i generate a win32/win64 executable using nasm? or for that matter any other executable like elf32/coff, which nasm says it supports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is:

```
ORG 100
```

which should be:

```
ORG 100h
```

The binary is a `.COM` so will load and run at `100h` regardless; the error means that the address calculated by the assembler for `msg` will be 156 bytes earlier than it should be, hence the extra junk.

The `ORG` directive is for the `bin` format only.  Other executable formats have sections (or segments).  (See the ["Output Formats"](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html) section of the [NASM manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/).)